# How to stop `Xorg` server?

Tags: xorg

When I start an Xorg server with the following command:

```
$ sudo Xorg -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER :1 -config /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

I get output like the following:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-140-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux Birth 5.4.0-86-generic #97~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 18 03:11:22 UTC 2021 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-86-generic root=UUID=2b7e3ed6-1058-4685-8601-ad09ba0245e2 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 08 April 2021  01:40:27PM
xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.5 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Fri Sep 24 21:39:21 2021
(++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

The Xorg server is running. But, how do I stop it? I tried `Ctrl+C`, but it doesn't work.

I am doing this in an Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   Your package details provided in your paste don't seem to *align* with any supported release of Ubuntu (it's like you've bits of various release; or haven't applied all upgrades; ie. 1.20.8 applies to install media; but should have been updated on a Ubuntu system)

Comment: Sorry for missing that info. Will add that to the question